# Simple python web/flask app on azure devops render(?) problem

Tags: python, html, flask, azure-devops, cloud

I have created a very basic python flask app for posting/getting files via html page that is rendered with render_template() function. Everything is working fine on localhost the problem came when I tried to deploy it to azure cloud. Everything was deployed successfully but when I open the link ( https://timakrest.azurewebsites.net/ ) it says not found. I had the problem on localhost when the render function couldnt find the index.html ..

```
path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + '\\templates'
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=path)
```

```
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The path is set up for the template folder (it is probably also the default setting of the flask but I wanted to tried..) I tried the dynamic absolute path as mentioned and static one as well but i somehow cannot figure it out..

I also somehow cannot find the python output in the cloud so I am not 100% sure its the .html thing but most probably..

Could you please help me ? ^^ thank you.

Comment: How did you deploy the python flask app to azure cloud? Could you share detailed steps?

Comment: Hello, well I pushed the code to the azure repo and then created pipeline  from azure repos git as "python to linux web app on azure" which created the yaml file you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy the python flask app from Azure Pipeline, you could refer to the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops

The first task under Build stage is UsePythonVersion, which specifies the version of Python to use on the build agent. hen we have script-based task that creates a virtual environment and installs dependencies from file (requirements.txt).

```
steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
       inputs:
         versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
         displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'
    - script: |
         python -m venv antenv
         source antenv/bin/activate
         python -m pip install --upgrade pip
         pip install setup
         pip install -r requirements.txt
       workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
       displayName: "Install requirements"
```

Next step creates the .zip file that the steps under deploy stage of the pipeline deploys. Then we have the task to upload the artifacts.

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
   inputs:
     rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
     includeRootFolder: false
     archiveType: 'zip'
     archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip'
     replaceExistingArchive: true
     verbose: # (no value); this input is optional
- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip
   displayName: 'Upload package'
   artifact: drop
```

> **Important**:
>
> When deploying to Azure App Service, be sure to use
> `includeRootFolder: false`. Otherwise, the contents of the .zip file
> are put in a folder named s, for "sources," which is replicated on the
> App Service. The App Service on Linux container then can't find the
> app code.

n the Deploy stage, we use the `deployment` keyword to define a deployment job targeting an environment.

```
jobs:
- deployment: DeploymentJob
pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)
environment: $(environmentName)
strategy:
  runOnce:
    deploy:
      steps:

      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
        displayName: 'Use Python version'

      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : {{ webAppName }}'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
          appName: $(webAppName)
          package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip

          # The following parameter is specific to the Flask example code. You may
          # or may not need a startup command for your app.
      startUpCommand: 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 startup:app'
```

Comment: My yaml looks exactly like this without the startUpCommand

Comment: Well I kinda fixed the issue i guess but it still doesnt work and this is what i get from pipeline logs

.
.

2021-03-07T03:05:02.724209317Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2021-03-07T03:05:03.473166758Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
2021-03-07T03:05:03.474425257Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ':/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
2021-03-07T03:05:03.482476050Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: 25: /opt/startup/startup.sh: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout: not found

Comment: You could try the sample in the link to see how's the result. Also, try to set `system.debug` to `true`, to see whether you can get more log.

Comment: Hello, sorry. I managed to run the web on azure by implementing my code to the tutorial code from MS (i still dont know what was the issue with my code). But now im facing problem with saving/downloading files via REST. Got internal error again. Tomorrow ill try to debug it and will see if i figure something out :(

Comment: Any update? What error did you get when saving/downloading files via REST?

Comment: Hello, I didnt get any useful logs but somehow managed it to work. I guess it had some problem with the path to the folder. I needed to change the folder to ./folder_name and it works fine now. Thank you for your help :)